# iOS In-House App Distribution

Tags: ios, distribution, enterprise

My client wants to control which device is running the app but also needs to distribute the app to more than 100 devices.

In case someone manages to get the .ipa he doesn't want him to be able to run it on a non authorized device.

I'm unsure about the following: under the enterprise development program can, and if so how, an app be tied to an device UUID (as for ad-hoc deployment) or do I have to secure the app distribution process entirely ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't have enough information to give you a company recommendation or software set, so I'll post this as a comment instead of an answer. Your client should check into mobile management solutions. Mobile management in a Google search will bring up several results. There are numerous enterprise solutions out there that allow enterprises to take full control of their devices, remote wipe/etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you distribute your app as an Enterprise app you can't tie it to a UDID like ad-hoc deployment (granted as an Enterprise developer you still have 100 devices you can distribute as ad-hoc to).

You can use TestFlight for distribution of Enterprise apps, it allows you to maintain lists of authorized users/devices and you can manage who gets builds etc such that **Testflight's installation process will only install your app onto devices you've authorized**.  Even if the email is opened on a unauthorized device it won't install.  Users could still endeavor to get your app off their device and try to install it elsewhere but...

If the devices are all < iOS6 you could references the devices' `uniqueIdentifier` and check that against a maintained list of UDID's such that the app can obviously still be installed but it couldn't be run.

Another alternative is requiring them to sign into the app on launch or it won't run.

Comment: UDID checking is inherently insecure anyway, since users buy/sell/lose devices.  An enterprise app should absolutely require login both to download/install, and to launch.

Comment: Using Testflight doesn't help in the case when the ipa file is given to other people unauthorized and then installed manually.

Comment: Agreed, authentication before install and authentication at launch are the best ways to go, I only threw that in there for completeness.

Comment: Also true about testflight, but the OP was wondering about creating a 'secure distribution process' and thats effectively what Testflight is, *secure distribution*.

Comment: For completeness: HockeyApp is another service that provides similar mechanisms to distribute apps as securely :) (Note: I am a co-founder of this service)

Comment: Isn't there any kind of certificate / profile that must also be installed on the client device and that ensures that the app can't run if such a profile is absent ?

Comment: @thomas.g Thats all handled by Testflight (or HockeyApp I assume)

Comment: @Shizam but not by any certificate/profile /something else from Apple ? (I'm trying to find a way but I'm getting ready to abandon all hopes  :-))

Comment: @thomas.g Correct, its not handled by apple (like ad-hoc is) but your Enterprise distribution provisioning profile is sent along with your application when you upload it and that is installed on the device.  Without it they couldn't run the app.

Comment: So the usecase: "the app is (somehow) grabbed by someone unauthorized" implies that the app can't be runned on a device without the right enterprise distribution provisioning profile, right ?

Comment: Ah yes, I misread your question and thought a sub-question was 'how to prevent unauthorized people from even getting the app', that wasn't a concern so nevermind that point.  You're right, they would have to get your app AND the provisioning profile.

Comment: You've answered all the use cases that were unclear to me, thank you ;)

Comment: The provisioning profile is included in the .ipa. Users do **not** need to install it separately.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement your own copy protection method if you want to ensure that enterprise apps are not installed on unauthorized devices. The enterprise provisioning profile does not include the UDID and they are no other means from Apple to specify the allowed devices.

Comment: Isn't there any kind of certificate / profile that must also be installed on the client device that ensures that the app can't run if such a profile is absent ?

Comment: The provisioning profile is included in the .ipa file. The user doesn't need to install a profile or certificate manually. If somebody gets a copy of your .ipa file, he can install it on any device.